# Get specific href attribute from another page

Tags: jquery, attributes, href

I'm using jQuery .get to grab elements from another page; I want to get the "nth" href attribute, which I'm trying to do with the code below. As you can see, I'm trying to change the value of an ID to a specific URL. I think there's a problem with my use of .find, but couldn't figure out. Thanks a ton for any help.

**JS**

```
$.get('/file.xml', function(data)
{
    var $links = $(data).find('a').attr('href'),
    selectedlink = $links.eq(selectedValue);
    var link = selectedlink.text();
    $("#fvlink").val(link);

});
```

**HTML page with URLs**

```
<body>
  <li><h2><a href="http://www.whatever1.coy">2060</a></h2><span class="desctext">This is the second slide</span></li>
  <li><h2><a href="http://www.whatever2.com">2057</a></h2><span class="desctext">This is the third slide</span></li>
  <li><h2><a href="http://www.whatever3.com">2056</a></h2><span class="desctext">This is the fourth slide</span></li>
</body>
```

Comment: , instead of ; after attr('href') for starters

Comment: Can you really use the data resource that way? It is a string, not something in a DOM tree. How do you want to apply a selector to a string?

Comment: Where does `selectedValue` come from?

Comment: is #fvlink a link or an input field? If it's a link, you can't assign val() to it.

Comment: #fvlink is an input field; selectedvalue is a number indicating which a element to focus on. thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `$(..).attr()` returns a string, `$links` won't be an jQuery object. You need to drop the call to `attr()`:

```
var $links = $(data).find('a');
```